# Named file descriptors with Process Substitution

Tags: bash, file-descriptors, process-substitution

I'm trying to use named file descriptors with Process Substitution.
I wrote the following code but it doesn't work:

```
# Open named file descriptors and associate to Process Substitution result
exec {folder1_files_list} < <( ls -v "${FOLDER1_PATH}"/* )
exec {folder2_files_list} < <( ls -v "${FOLDER2_PATH}"/* )

IFS=$'\n' read -r folder1_filename -u "${folder1_files_list}"
IFS=$'\n' read -r folder2_filename -u "${folder2_files_list}"

# Close named file descriptors
exec {folder1_files_list}<-
exec {folder2_files_list}<-
```

The error is:

```
exec: {folder1_files_list}: not found
```

I've read through the bash manual but probably missing something

Comment: oh man, it was the space!

Comment: Yes, the space matters, also you probably need `exec {folder1_files_list}<&-` (with the `&`) to close the fd.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full valid code, for our future generation:

```
exec {folder1_files_list}< <( ls -v -1 "${FOLDER1}"/* )
# Usage example:
# If I want to output the entire contents of the file descriptor, 
# then I should write:
#   cat - <&$folder1_files_list

exec {folder2_files_list}< <( ls -v -1 "${FOLDER2}"/* )

IFS=$'\n' read -r -u $folder1_files_list folder1_filename
IFS=$'\n' read -r -u $folder2_files_list folder2_filename

exec {folder1_files_list}<&-
exec {folder2_files_list}<&-
```